# Get Service Account Details of the SQL Agent Service

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, wmi-query

How can I get the Service Account name for the SQL Agent service for a particular SQL Server (SQL 2005).
Is it possible to get using SQL statements or WMI ?

Comment: Just asking the DBA would really be the most appropriate way to get this information. I know that I wouldn't want anyone trying to poke around my SQL Server programatically in order to find out what accounts the services are being run under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sc.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx).

To find SQL instances services:

```
sc \\<remote computer name> query | find /i "sql"
```

To get configuration:

```
sc \\<remote computer name> qc <service name from listing above>
```

Comment: If you want to use powershell, make sure to call it with `sc.exe` so you don't use the alias for `set-content`.  As mentioned in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters.aspx), you can also use more Powershell Friendly commands like [`Get-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

As Aaron Bertrand pointed out, you can use the undocumented `xp_regread` in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008, but there is a better way, starting with SQL Server 2008R2 SP1.

From the article [How to identify the SQL Server Service Account in T-SQL](http://sqlity.net/en/1868/identify-sql-server-service-account-in-t-sql/), you can use [`sys.dm_server_services`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204542.aspx) like this:

```sql
SELECT  DSS.servicename,
        DSS.startup_type_desc,
        DSS.status_desc,
        DSS.last_startup_time,
        DSS.service_account,
        DSS.is_clustered,
        DSS.cluster_nodename,
        DSS.filename,
        DSS.startup_type,
        DSS.status,
        DSS.process_id
FROM    sys.dm_server_services AS DSS;
```

[image: SQL Service Account Query Results]

Answer (score 8):

For a default instance:

```
DECLARE @sn NVARCHAR(128);

EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SQLSERVERAGENT',
    'ObjectName', 
    @sn OUTPUT;

SELECT @sn;
```

For a named instance, you'll need the second argument to be:

```
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SQLAGENT$InstanceName',
```

Now, it may not work because you may not have access to xp_regread, and the location of this property may change from version to version (I only tested 2008, 2008 R2 and Denali - I don't have a 2005 instance handy to check).

In any case you are probably better off asking the DBA (as suggested in a comment) or, if you have access to the physical machine, just checking the service account in the Control Panel.

Comment: Note that if you have named instances then you should replace MSSQL$InstanceName with SQLAGENT$InstanceName or else you will be looking at the service account for SQL Database service rather than SQL Agent.

Answer (score 8):

Since SQL Server runs as a windows service you can use [wmic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28VS.85%29.aspx) to query the start name.

```
wmic service where "name Like 'MSSQL%'" get Name , StartName
```

For me this outputs the following (since I've got multiple instances thoes are included as well)

```
Name                    StartName
MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS        NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS2005    NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
MSSQLFDLauncher         NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
MSSQLSERVER             NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
MSSQLServerADHelper     NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
MSSQLServerADHelper100  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
MSSQLServerOLAPService  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

You can add `/NODE` to query remote computers. As with any WMI query you will need sufficient privileges in order for this to work

Or the same query using [Powershell's Get-WmiObject](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/15/the-scripting-wife-uses-powershell-to-find-service-accounts.aspx) (Supports remote/multiple computersnames):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName localhost,W-Remote -Filter "name Like 'MSSQL%'" | ft __Server,State,Name,DisplayName,StartName -AutoSize
```

Sample Output:

```
__SERVER State   Name                   DisplayName                         StartName
-------- -----   ----                   -----------                         ---------
W0123456 Stopped MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS       SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)             NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
W0123456 Running MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)            LocalSystem
W0123456 Stopped MSSQLServerADHelper100 SQL Active Directory Helper Service NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE
W-REMOTE Stopped MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS       SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)             NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
W-REMOTE Running MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)            LocalSystem
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but here is my solution. This has been tested against SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016.

```
if (select CONVERT(INT, (REPLACE(SUBSTRING(convert(nvarchar, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')), 1, 2), '.', '')))) >10
BEGIN
select distinct(service_account) AS SvcAccount from sys.dm_server_services;
END

ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE @instanceName varchar(100)
set @instanceName    = convert(varchar,SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName'))
IF (@instanceName) IS NULL
begin
DECLARE @sn NVARCHAR(128);
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SQLSERVERAGENT',
    'ObjectName', 
    @sn  OUTPUT ;

SELECT @sn AS SvcAccount;
END
ELSE
BEGIN 

DECLARE @SQL varchar (500)
SET @SQL  = 'DECLARE @sn NVARCHAR(128); exec master.dbo.xp_regread ''HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'', ''SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SQLAgent$'+@instanceName+''',''ObjectName'', @sn OUTPUT; SELECT @sn AS SvcAccount;'
EXEC (@SQL)

END
END
```